# Android changed value stored in program

Tags: java, android, passwords

I have a dialog where the user have to write the password. If it is appropriate then will open another a dialog where the user can change some settings. Is there any why to save the changed value in to exactly to the program or I have to write in to file and realoaded from there. But  I think it is not so safty if I want to hide this settings from simple users.

Which is the best solutions for that?

Comment: Use *Shared Preferences* http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

As long as you store a hashed version of the password there shouldn't be a problem.

When you check the password you then check against the hashed version.

Whether you choose to store it in a flat file, or database doesn't matter, for me if it was just a couple of users I would be tempted by some config file, if multiple users might use the same device I might use a database.  It also depends if my users are going to have other associated data.

Comment: I dont have to care with the password I am just opening a dialog and I would like to stora my changes without file of it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPrefernces](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for this purpose. Or, you can try [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) provided by Android.

**Edit**
This code allows you to enter some text in `EditText` and when you click `Save` it will be saved. The saved text would be displayed in `EditText` when the app is opened again.

MainActivity.java

```
package pcsalt.example.sharedprefdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et;
    Button btn;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                editor = pref.edit();
                String text = et.getText().toString();
                editor.putString("key_value", text);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });

        et.setText(pref.getString("key_value", "default value"));
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Some text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can U show me an example? I have a string value which countains some string when I click the save button then should change the value

Comment: I would like to change forexample the ip address so it has a start value and if smb get in to the settings menu then you can change the ip number